# tmux-resurrect is not restoring my running commands

Tags: tmux, cygwin

I'm using the [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin to recreate tmux sessions after tmux is shutdown. It mostly works but it is not restoring running commands. I've tried with `vim`, `less`, `man` and `tail`, all supported, but I get nothing but a waiting bash prompt.

Here's the save data for one pane that was running `vim test.txt` as seen in one of the save files in
`~/.tmux/resurrect`:

`pane    0       1       :bash   1       :*      2       :/tmp     0       vim     :`

Clearly something is missing here. Where is "test.txt"? Pretty hard to recreate a
command if the arguments aren't persisted.

Why aren't full commands being saved?

I am running this on Cygwin which I suspect is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is the hobbled version of `ps` that Cygwin provides
because, in their words, 
*due to the limitations of simulating a POSIX environment under Windows, there is
little information to give.* In particular this version of `ps` will not show
command arguments. The solution is to install a more helpful substitute for `ps`
and integrate it into tmux-resurrect.

Start by installing `pgrep`. This can be found in the Cygwin package
`psutils-ng` (For 64-bit Cygwin. For 32-bit it might still be called just `psutils`.)

Now we need to tell `tmux-resurrect` to use it. Fortunately it already has a
*strategy* available to use this tool. However, it's not quite compatible with the
Cygwin version so edit the file
`[tmux-resurrect-install-dir]/save_command_strategies/pgrep.sh` and change

```
\pgrep -lf -P "$PANE_PID" |
```

to

```
\pgrep -af -P "$PANE_PID" |
```

That's a single letter change, <kbd>l</kbd> to <kbd>a</kbd>.

Finally, tell the plugin to use this strategy by adding this line to your
`.tmux.conf` file after any other resurrect configuration:

```
set -g @resurrect-save-command-strategy 'pgrep'
```

That should do it. Next time a session is saved the example given above should look
more like this:

`pane    0       1       :bash   1       :*      2       :/tmp     0       vim     :vim test.txt`

Upon restore that file will be loaded into `vim`.

Answer (score 1):

The newer version does help with this:

https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect/blob/master/docs/restoring_programs.md

I had to add the following to my `.tmux.conf` to make it work better:

```
# Plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum'
# Plugin Config
set -g @resurrect-processes 'python sqlite3 nano'
set -g @resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on'
set -g @continuum-boot 'on'
set -g @continuum-restore 'on'
```

Fetch plugins  + **I**     (capital I)

Update plugins  + **U**      (capital U)

Save:  + **ctrl + s**

Restore:  + **ctrl + r**

The resultant dated save files can be edited at .tmux/resurrect

`last` is symbolic link to the last file, if tmux crashes on start up just `cp` a working / older one over the most recent that last is pointing to.

[Some users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128190/tmux-exits-immediately-after-starting) find temporarily adding new-session at the start of .tmux.conf flushes things out.

source: [https://jdhao.github.io/2019/01/17/tmux_plugin_management](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/01/17/tmux_plugin_management/)